# Position image in image

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I put an little image in the upper right corner of an larger picture like the popup with a number over the App Store icon?

Greets

miny

Comment: why would you tag this as "jQuery"?

Comment: Maybe jQuery has a function to put an picture in the corner who is dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a div that contains the image and the small image:

```
<div style="position:relative">
   <img src="...image-url...">
   <img src="...small-image-url..."
        style="position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Would you need to specify z-index of the images, or will the second image called always take priority over the first? Just curious!

Comment: @boundless08: the second image will always be in the front because it's following the first one in the children list order.

Answer (score 0):

If you position you small image 'absolute' you can position it relative to the place it stood using positive and negative margin. You can also position it using left,right,bottom,top and set pixels relative to your window.

Example:

```
 .smallimage{
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:-20px;/*relative to its original position*/
 }
```

Or

```
 .smallimage{
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:10px;/*relative to the window*/
 }
```